# Rollover counter

Tags: go, rollover

I am writing code for a rollover counter in Go. The code gets accessed every time a new value from the PLC counter comes in. When the value reaches above 32768, the PLC counter resets to 1 and roll over is assigned a value of 1. I need to write a code that can count the number of resets and store those resets in the memory such that whenever the code is restarted the previous value of reset is available for use in calculation.

The formula for counting is below:

**Total count = count + 32768*number of resets**

**Update:**
I have written the following code for the rollover counting but as soon as the value of rollover reaches 1, **the total count becomes 132769 instead of 32768.** **The value of rollover counter gets stored as 1 in the rollover.data file but when it is accessed it is getting extracted as 11.**

input1 and input2 are basically the consecutive values coming from PLC counter in a 2 event count window. For example the initial values will be input1 = 0 input2 = 0 and then (input2 = 1, input1 =0), (input2 = 2, input1 =1) etc. So by that logic when input2 = 32768, the value of rollover should increment by 1. After this value the PLC counter gets reset to 1.

```
package main
   

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var input1 int = 32768
    var input2 int = 1

    if input1 == 0 {

        t := strconv.Itoa(0)
        mydata := []byte(t)
        recordfile := []byte(t)

        // the WriteFile method returns an error if unsuccessful
        err := ioutil.WriteFile("rollover.data", mydata, 0777)
        // handle this error
        if err != nil {
            // print it out
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        err2 := ioutil.WriteFile("record.data", recordfile, 0777)
        // handle this error
        if err2 != nil {
            // print it out
            fmt.Println(err2)
        }
    }

    rollover, err := ioutil.ReadFile("rollover.data")
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", rollover)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    rollovervalue, err3 := strconv.Atoi(string(rollover))

    if err3 == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%T \n %v", rollovervalue, rollovervalue)
    }

    //fmt.Printf("%T", rollovervalue)
    totalcount := input2 + rollovervalue*32768

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", totalcount)

    if input2 == 32768 {
        
        t := strconv.Itoa(rollovervalue + 1)
        mydata := []byte(t)
        err := ioutil.WriteFile("rollover.data", mydata, 0777)
       
        if err != nil {
            // print it out
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

    }

}
```

,,,

Comment: So is your question essentially how to store a number in a file?

Comment: Yes, storing the value in the file and accessing it when the program restarts.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @Adrian updated the question. Cannot seem to get it entirely correctly.

Comment: @AhsanCheema what problems do you have with this code? What doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 6):

The contents of a variable are lost when the process exits.

You need a way to persist the rollover counter when the process exits. There are a lot of ways to achieve this:

- create a file and write the value to the file whenever it changes. On program startup, read the file if it exists.
- use some kind of database (an SQL database like MySQL, SQLite, Redis, etc.).